# using a PHP print_r array result in javascript/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a simple jquery/ajax request to the server which returns the structure and data of an array. I was wondering if there was a quick way in which I can use this array structure and data using jquery;

A simple request;

```
var token = $("#token").val();
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', url: './', data: 'token=' + token + '&re=8', cache: false, timeout: 5000,
    success: function(html){ 
        // do something here with the html var 
    }                           
});
```

the result ( actual result from PHP's print_r(); );

```
    Array
    (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [username] => Emmalene
                [contents] => 
                              <ul><li class="name">ACTwebDesigns</li><li class="speech">helllllllo</li></ul>
                              <ul><li class="name">ACTwebDesigns</li><li class="speech">sds</li></ul>
                              <ul><li class="name">ACTwebDesigns</li><li class="speech">Sponge</li><li class="speech">dick</li></ul>
                              <ul><li class="name">ACTwebDesigns</li><li class="speech">arghh</li></ul>
            )

    )
```

I was thinking along the lines of

```
var demo = Array(html); // and then do something with the demo var
```

Not sure if that would work it just sprang to mind.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [JSON](http://www.json.org/). JSON is a lightweight data-interchange format which makes it easy to transfer data between different programming languages.

Use [`json_encode`](http://fi.php.net/json_encode) in PHP to encode your data:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

And in jQuery, define that the result is in `JSON` format and jQuery will automatically parse it as such:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url: './', data: 'token=' + token + '&re=8',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(obj) { 
        // obj is now the same array as JS object:
        $.each(obj, function(index, row) {
            alert(row.username);
        });            
    }                           
});
```

Comment: sorry I can only vote one for the answer but thanks all. One other thing ( i really am bad a javascript ) how do I loop through the results?

Comment: @Phil Jackson, I modified my answer to include an example of looping through the results using jQuery's `each()` method.

Comment: @Phil Jackson, you can also try `for()` loops, there's plenty of coverage on that subject even here on SO, so I won't go in deeper detail in that. Post a new question if you have problems! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/json_encode). It turns the array into JSON data that is directly usable in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on your PHP script. This will return a JSON encoded data that you can directly use in javascript:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: './', 
    data: { token: token, re: '8' }, 
    cache: false, 
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data){ 
        // data will already be a javascript object that you can manipulate
    }                           
});
```

Comment: `data` will not be an javascript object unless you specify `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: It will be if the server sends the correct content type: `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: I have not writen a content type nor changed type to 'json' but still returns correctly alert(JSON_array[0].username); returns emmalene